# Check for a value of key, which is present in many different parents keys inside a object in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, object

Lets consider we have a object as shown below ,

```
"fruit_quantities" : {
  "batch1": {
    mango : 100,
    apple: 50
  },
  "batch2": {
    mango : 0,
    apple: 50
   },
  "batch3": {
    mango : 0,
    apple: 50
   }
}
```

I just need to find if the value of `mango` is greater than 0, irrespective of which `batch` is it in.
How would I do this in javascript?

Comment: What did you tried ? What is your desired output ?

Comment: I was trying with Object.map , i think that was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using the combination of [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method like this:

```js
var fruit_quantities = {
  "batch1": {
    mango : 100,
    apple: 50
  },
  "batch2": {
    mango : 0,
    apple: 50
   },
  "batch3": {
    mango : 0,
    apple: 50
   }
};

var fruit = "mango";
var r = Object.keys(fruit_quantities).some(function(key) {
  return fruit_quantities[key][fruit] > 0;
});

console.log(r);
```

Comment: Thank you, Looks good. Dont know why i didnt think about this solution.